# How to hide API links & React JS code from Dev tools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

I've built a web app using React JS which is getting data from an API

[image: Screenshot of the app]

If I go to "Inspect Elements" and go to sources, I'm able to see my code

[image: Source Code Screen Shot]

My Question is :- Is it possible to hide this and all other code?
Here's the link of the App :- https://recipeee-54899.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Fundamentally, no, not really. If you send code for the client to execute, the client will be able to see it.

Comment: If you manage to hide all code from the client, any requests made can still be viewed  including the query params and headers. So you probably don't want to include your api key in requests to APIs...

Comment: I'm hiding the api in my .env file. So API is not the problem anymore. I think I have to render the website using Express JS or any sort of backend. Will that work, Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide this code as far as I know.

You can use webpack (which I saw you already use in your app) to make your code not readable. I suggest you'll use webpack to make [a bundle of your js code into one file](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/#creating-a-bundle) and [production mode](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification) to minify your code so it will be very hard to read it.